# Why am i getting a error running send2trash

Tags: python, oserror

> trying to run send2trash from my directory `C:\\Users\\Ken` and was given a error.

```
\`
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File \~\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\send2trash\\plat_win_modern.py:61, in send2trash(paths)
60     fileop.DeleteItem(item, sink)
\---\> 61 result = fileop.PerformOperations()
62 aborted = fileop.GetAnyOperationsAborted()

com_error: (-2144927705, 'OLE error 0x80270027', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In \[31\], in \<cell line: 1\>()
\----\> 1 send2trash.send2trash('practice.txt')

File \~\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\send2trash\\plat_win_modern.py:69, in send2trash(paths)
65         raise OSError(None, None, paths, result)
66 except pywintypes.com_error as error:
67     # convert to standard OS error, allows other code to get a
68     # normal errno
\---\> 69     raise OSError(None, error.strerror, path, error.hresult)
70 finally:
71     # Need to make sure we call this once fore every init
72     pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

OSError: \[WinError -2144927705\] OLE error 0x80270027: 'C:\\Users\\Ken\\Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp-master\\12-Advanced Python Modules\\practice.txt'
\
```

Does anyone know what this means?

I tried.

> send2trash.send2trash('random.txt')

Hoping it will send the txt file to my trash

Comment: 0x80270027 is COPYENGINE_E_SHARING_VIOLATION_SRC.  You didn't have permission to move that file.  Is the file open somewhere?

Comment: no when i opened it i closed it in the same cell in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the file you're attempting to delete is being held by another process.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34954690)